# Buttons for SharePoint list filter

Tags: list, sharepoint, filter, web-parts

I have a SharePoint list with 100k+ records with the following fields:

- Market (about 10 different choices);
- Market Unit (about 10 Market Units per each Market);
- Project (there could be a lot of them).

In order for a user to find a project they first need to filter by Market, then by Market Unit, etc. and this is a painful exercise for such a large list.

Is it possible instead to create a SharePoint Page where I can add 10 buttons for Markets, then dynamically add buttons for Market Units and connect these buttons to the SharePoint list to get it filtered when a button is pressed? Did anyone come across any similar solution?

Or, maybe another option would be to create a lot of different Views for the List and create some buttons so when a user clicks on a button a view of the list is changed?

Comment: did you find solution?